# unity hub does not let me install unity; error: "There is not enough space to download and install the selected items"

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I'm pretty sure this is not the right forum for asking a question like this therefore I would really appreciate it someone links me to a better forum for this question (if needed).

**My problem:**

In the unity hub I have it set so that the unity editors should download in a folder on my hard drive. However, when I click to install unity, it says there is not enough space. I believe this is because the unity hub ignored my request to install onto my hard drive (which has 180 gigabytes left) and tries to install it into my ssd (which only has 888 mb left).

It's either Unity's fault, or the fact that even though I'm telling unity to install onto my hard drive, it still needs to download some files onto my ssd and there is just not enough space. Hopefully one of you will know the answer to this problem.

Comment: I think this question is on-topic here under *"software tools commonly used by programmers"* as mentioned in [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) even though this site is more focused on problems with source code. You could also try other stack exchange sites like [gamedev.stackexchange.com](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) for more targeted responses.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Download the needed unity version directly here: https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download/archive
2. Then install it on your hdd.
3. Link the installed editor to Unity hub, inside the hub.

Comment: This link is missing some versions. I cannot download Unity Editor 2020.3.24f1 on Linux. "Unity Accelerator" is the only choice in the dropdown menu.

Answer (score 2):

Just redefine your installation path (Unity editors path) from unity hub preferences. It worked for me.

Comment: Worked for me too, ty

Comment: This has helped me. Couldn't seem to figure out how to get Unity to install to my portable SSD. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The unity hub, first downloads into it's temporary directory in C:\users<username(s)>\Appdata , which is a hidden folder, that's why it doesn't appear , in order to see this you to check the hidden checkbox in the view tab in your file explorer (btw this worked with me on windows , idk if this gonna work on other OS but you can try) . It does this first and then installs the Editor and still needs a little more space to install like 3gb of data . So, depending on your requirements check if your C drive , even if your installing on another drive . TLDR ; Check your C drive compalsary .