# cant get unity hub to install unity editor

Tags: unity-game-engine

So, when I try to install the unity editor from unity hub 2.4.3, it says I don't have enough memory. I have over 600 gigabytes, which should be more than enough. I think it might be trying to install on another drive, and if it is, it wont give me an option to change which drive it will download to. How would I make it install to the right location? If this isn't the right place to ask, please show me where to ask this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [unity hub does not let me install unity; error: "There is not enough space to download and install the selected items"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58674292/unity-hub-does-not-let-me-install-unity-error-there-is-not-enough-space-to-do)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the potential reasons for Unity being unable to install an instance of Unity Editor as you mentioned could be a lack of space in the specific drive that you're trying to install the editor on.

In order to change the install location, go to preferences by clicking on the gear icon in Unity Hub:
[image]

After that, you should see `Unity Editors Path` which you can use to change the install location of all the Unity editors:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

On the mac the problem for me was, that the folder was not writable. I changed the owner of the directory to my user and the installtion worked.